# NgbDatepicker in Reactive Forms with formly: Set Initial Value

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap, angular-formly

I am trying to use the ngbDatepicker in an angular reactive form and would want to be able to display the initial value.

My question in this is [very similar to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238064/ngbdatepicker-in-reactive-forms-set-initial-value) with the crucial difference, that I am also using [formly](https://formly.dev/), an angular package to automate away form generation. As the answer to the original question is based on generating a new formControl and adding it to the form, which in my case is done by formly, which is why I'm struggling.

The "component" generally functions when you want to enter a new value (because that triggers an event which I use to change the model value), but the initial value isn't displayed properly. While the model always has the value of e.g. "2020-07-05" if inspected with augury, this is never displayed in the input-field. This stays true if I convert the date in the model to an NgbDate ({year, month, day}) in ngOnInit().

Formly calls my custom component (defined below) that contains solely the field and binds the pre-existing formcontrol (including model) and field-configurations to the input field. The component itself doesn't do much, it contains the necessary HTML for the ngbDatepicker and a function that, when a date is chosen, converts it from an NgbDate ({year, month, day}) to a string ("yyyy-mm-dd") and ensures that that is stored in the model instead of the NgbDate. It also opens the datepicker when you click on fa-calendar icon:

```
//formly-datepicker.component.html

<div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'d-none': to.hidden}">
    <!-- Heading --> 
    <!-- to = TemplateOptions -->
    <label for="datepicker">
        <strong>
            {{to.label}}
            <span *ngIf="to.required">*</span>
        </strong>
    </label>

    <!-- Input -->
    <div class="input-group">
        <input
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
        name="datepicker" 
        [formControl]="formControl" 
        [formlyAttributes]="field" 
        ngbDatepicker 
        #datepickerInput="ngbDatepicker"
        (dateSelect)="inputDateToField($event)"
        >
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <div class="btn btn-outline-light fa fa-calendar" (click)="datepickerInput.toggle()"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<ng-template #customDay let-date>
    <div class="datepicker-day btn-light">
        {{ date.day }}
    </div>
</ng-template>



//formly-datepicker.component.ts
import { Component, } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbDate } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formly-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './formly-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formly-datepicker.component.scss']
})
export class FormlyDatepickerComponent extends FieldType{
  inputDateToField(event: NgbDate){
    this.model.session_date = `${event.year}-${event.month}-${event.day}`;
  }
}
```

I have tried manipulating the model in ngOnInit() and ngAfterViewInit(), I have tried setting startDate, but nothing seems to help in this case. What am I to do here?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? Even I'm facing the exact same issue. It works when the custom template is a simple textbox, but not when I update it to an `ngbDatepicker`

Comment: @Aashwath Acharya Sadly not. I typically update my questions with a detailed explanation of the solution I found, but this one has eluded me to this day.

Comment: it was actually working for me, I was passing in the date in an incorrect format instead of YYYY-MM-DD. The difference may lie in the configs of the NgBootstrap and Formly libraries. Have elaborated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would urge you to update the configs for both NgBootstrap and Formly (if you haven't already):

1. Instead of using the `inputDateToField` method in your component, create these [two services (parser and adapter)](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter) recommended by NgBootstrap for the NgbDatePicker. The parser will maintain the format you specify in the `model` and the adapter will display the date in the UI, again as per your customization. E.g. I use the parser to convert the ISO string the backend provides to save it as 'YYYY-MM-DD' in my `model` and the adapter to display it as 'DD-MM-YYYY'
2. Wherever you import `FormlyModule` update the config like so (if it isn't in the AppModule, you may have to use `forChild`):

```js
FormlyModule.forRoot({types: [{ name: 'date', component: FormlyDatepickerComponent, extends: 'input'}]})
```

3. In your `FormlyDatepickerComponent`'s template, add `type="text"` (optional).

Comment: The "extends: input" bit is in fact not needed. For my particular issue, implementing a `CustomAdapter` and a `CustomDateParserFormatter` sufficed in fixing the issue.

Comment: @PhilippDoerner forgot to mention it's optional. The `extends` property will automate other field options such as label, validation error messages etc. Else you'll have to explicitly include code for them in your component

Answer (score 1):

you can take two aproach:

1.-when create the form use as defaultValue a NgbDateStruct

```
//I imagine you has an object "data" with a property "date" 
//in the way yyyy-mm-dd and create the field as
{
      key: 'date',
      type: 'input',
      defaultValue: {
           year:+data.date.substr(0,4),
           month:+data.date.substr(5,2),
           day:+data.date.substr(8,2)
      },
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'First Name (initialized via default value)',
      },
    },
```

In this case you're always mannage the "date" an an object with properties year,month and day, yes, a FormControl can be store an object, it's not "extrange"

2.- Use a custom Adapter that mannage a string. It's a bit complex. You need create two class:

CustomAdepter

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomAdapter extends NgbDateAdapter<string> {

  readonly DELIMITER = '-';

  fromModel(value: string | null): NgbDateStruct | null {
    if (value) {
      let date = value.split(this.DELIMITER);
      return {
        day : parseInt(date[2], 10),
        month : parseInt(date[1], 10),
        year : parseInt(date[0], 10)
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  toModel(date: NgbDateStruct | null): string | null {
    return date ? date.year+ this.DELIMITER+('00'+date.month).slice(-2) + this.DELIMITER + ('00'+date.day).slice(-2)   : null;
  }
}
```

and CustomDateParserFormatter (makes that when you enter an input create the ngbDateStructurt)

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

  readonly DELIMITER = '-';

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct | null {
    if (value) {
      const separator=value.indexOf(".")>=0?".":value.indexOf("-")>=0?"-":value.indexOf("/")>=0?"/":null
      if (separator)
      {
      let date = value.split(separator);
      return {
        day : parseInt(date[2], 10),
        month : parseInt(date[1], 10),
        year : parseInt(date[0], 10)
      };
    }
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct | null): string {
    return date ? date.year+ this.DELIMITER+('00'+date.month).slice(-2) + this.DELIMITER + ('00'+date.day).slice(-2)   : "";
  }
}
```

Then in your component you need add as providers in your module (you can also add as providers in your component)

```
  providers: [
    {provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: CustomAdapter},
    {provide: NgbDateParserFormatter, useClass: CustomDateParserFormatter}
  ]
```

Now you can use  and your model or formControl will be a string

a [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uzht8r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) the example in [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter)